# Debugging with LG P500 in windows 7 pro 64bit (unsigned drivers)

Tags: android, debugging, drivers, unsigned, lg

I recently updated windows 7 64bit to SP1 and my LG P500 to Android 2.2.2, so I don't know which one of this may have caused this issued.

here's the error when installing drivers:

> Windows cannot verify the digital
>   signature for the drivers required for
>   this device. A recent hardware or
>   software change might have installed a
>   file that is signed incorrectly or
>   damaged, or that might be malicious
>   software from an unknown source. (Code
>   52)

Can anyone help me on this?

Is there anyway than turning off the need for signed drivers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with Windows. do the first thing is to disable UAC from control panel, also refer to this link http://www.techspot.com/vb/topic127187.html

Comment: It worked! However, before SP1 I didn't have any problem... Damn Microsoft... There should by a Developers Edition :D

Answer (score 0):

You have to sign the drivers using test certificate and enable such test certificates on start. List above has working tutorial how to do that, you need to sign lgandadb.sys and WdfCoInstaller01005.dll. You will have test mode on desktop in down right corner when that is active. Please write to LG support, maybe they will invest one more certificate for driver.

Other way is to use linux to devel on LG, as it does not require external drivers at all. Only to set permissions on usb device.